# Textarea with irregular border, onfocus border color change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

So I have a text area with borders that look something like this:

[image]

Any idea how I should go about changing border color on focus?

Obviously it would be easy if it had regular css border instead of images, but I'm not sure how to do it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the same kind of method you would use for non-image implementations:

```
.chatBox {
    background-image: url('border.png');
}

.chatBox:hover, .chatBox:focus {
    background-image: url('border-highlight.png');
}
```

Obviously your border is more complex than this, but you can see the concept is the same. If you are using nested elements, it should still work. If you get stuck, show some code and I'll do my best to help.

Comment: Thanks. Also thank you to everyone else for pure CSS ideas, those are interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Another [workaround in pure CSS](http://jsbin.com/ewahuv/2/edit) working on `focus` event (unfortunately :focus pseudoclass is not working on IE<=8)

Just tried with Firefox. On webkit some adjustment/extra style are required, but it is simply to give you an idea to work on, but for the amount of css and the tricky element positioning I strongly prefer the background solution

Relevant CSS and HTML

```
<fieldset>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <label>insert text here</label>
</fieldset>



fieldset { 
   position: relative; 
   padding : 0 0 3em 0; 
   border  : 0;
}
label {
   position : absolute;
   top  : 0;
   left : 0;
}

textarea {
   position : relative;
   z-index  : 5;
   top      : 3em;
   width    : 300px;
   height   : 120px;
   border   : 1px #ccc solid;
}

label:before {
  content   : "";
  display   : block;
  width     : 15px;
  height    : 15px;
  border    : 1px #ccc solid;
  position  : absolute;
  top       : 31px;
  left      : 20px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

label:after {
  content   : "";
  display   : block;
  position  : absolute;
  z-index   : 10;
  left      : 17px;
  top       : 40px;
  width     : 23px;
  height    : 1px;
  background : #fff; 
}

textarea:focus, 
textarea:focus + label:before {
   border-color : red; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A pure CSS solution: put the `textarea` in a `div` and use another `div` after the `textarea` to get the border shape.

### [*DEMO*](http://dabblet.com/gist/3697832)

HTML:

```
<div class='container'><textarea></textarea><div class='c'></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.container { display: inline-block; position: relative; }
textarea {
    width: 20em;
    border: solid 2px;
}
.c {
    position: absolute;
    top: -.4em; left: 2em;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    border-top: solid 2px;
    border-left: solid 2px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background: white;
}
textarea:focus, textarea:hover, textarea:focus + .c, textarea:hover + .c {
    border-color: red;
    outline: none;
}
```